# Can't get my head around 'a line is one kind of curve.'

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, curves

While I was reading [How not to be wrong](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0143127535) by [Jordan Ellenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_Ellenberg), at one point came across this, *"a line is one kind of curve, but not the only kind and lines enjoy all kinds of special properties that curves in general may not."* Can someone explain this, please?
Thanks in advance.

P.s: What are those *special properties* that he is talking about?

Comment: cf. a square is a quadrangle, but not the only kind, as it has special properties other quadrangles do not have (like all sides having equal length and all angles being straight).

Answer (score -1):

Two lines (in the plane) always intersect or otherwise are disjoint, while curves can intersect in any number of points, to name but one special property. Lines are homogeneous (all points look the same) etc.

Comment: Thanks Henno. Can you refer to any resources where I can find all of these special properties?

Comment: @TheDude they’re obvious IMHO.

Comment: @The Dude Any text on Euclidean geometry.

Comment: @Henno, homogeneity is not a distinguishing property of a line. All simple curves are homogeneous. Lines are distinguished by their geometry, not their topology.

Comment: @SteveB agreed, but curves need not be simple, was my point. Lines always are.

Comment: Circles are quite homogeneous as well.

Comment: @badjohn figure eight isn’t

Comment: Indeed, some curves are homogeneous and some aren't.  My point was that homogeneity alone does not determine a line.  Necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: @badjohn the OP asked for special (but not necessary and sufficient properties) of a line vis à vis general curves.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that you were wrong.  It was just a clarification.